# Sharing a db connection between threads in a C# application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have found there to be very little information on this topic, was hoping someone could direct me to some information and possible sample code.

Comment: I guess this also differs from database to database vendor...mysql, ms sql, sqlite...

Answer (score 11):

Generally connections are not thread safe(SqlConnection ,MySqlConnection and OracleConnection specifically mention that they are not thread safe).

Don't share a connection between threads.

Answer (score 6):

I would say dont share the connection object itself, just create a new connection and let ADO.net handle connection pooling.

Comment: I tend to agree, Database server are designed to manage connection pooling, it's best to let the DB server what it was designed to do.

Answer (score 3):

To respond to the actual parameters of the question, rather than dismissing them, I would wrap the `DbCommand` to help synchronize access to the connection (**if and only if** you absolutely have to).

```
public class SyncedDbCommand : DbCommand
{
    private DbCommand _cmd;
    private object _sync;

    public SyncedDbCommand(DbCommand cmd, object sync)
    {
        _cmd = cmd;
        _sync = sync;
    }

    // omitted basic proxy method overrides

    protected override DbDataReader ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_sync);
        return _cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public override int ExecuteNonQuery()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_sync);
        return _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public override object ExecuteScalar()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_sync);
        return _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_sync);
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

To use the sample, you have to instantiate it with an actual `DbCommand` **as well as** some object instance that is shared across all usages of a connection. In the simplest use, you could even pass the connection object itself as the lock object. The instantiation should occur in a `using` statement. This does not absolve you from knowing exactly what your usage requirements are and how the `Monitor` class and locking work.

One way or another, you want to synchronize usage of the connection across threads, and the above is one approach to doing so.

Comment: Absolutely do NOT do this, there is no good reason to do so and you will affect the performance of your application. Use connection pooling like the above answer states.

Comment: "No good reason"? Without knowing the architecture of his code how can you claim that? As for sharing a connection, it's a well known method to enable transactions without promoting to MSDTC. This is a huge performance benefit. Nevertheless, starting from scratch, of course I would not advise the approach described in my answer. But in *respecting the asker and responding to the particulars of his question*, this is my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample code out in the wild because (almost) no one does it because it is such a very, very, bad idea.