# How to force one connection in EF Core Sqlite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am using a SQLite database file to test my EF Core application in place of the SQL Server database. I am running into an issue because the dependency injection is passing in new instances of the dbContext with new connections, so I get an exception when it tries to do certain things, for example when creating an entity and then trying to send an email.

> The transaction object is not associated with the same connection object as this command.

How can I set up my `Startup.cs` so that it passes around just one connection?

`ConfigureServices()`:

```
if (_env.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext, InventoryDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(sqliteConnectionString, o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery))
            .AddInterceptors(new QueueSaveChangesInterceptor(), new QueueDbTransactionInterceptor()));
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

`Configure()`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
    Application.SetupContext(scope.ServiceProvider);

    using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<InventoryDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync().Wait();
    context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().Wait();

    SqliteDbSeeder.SeedTestDatabase(context);
}
```

Should I be thinking in a different direction?

Comment: First of all: Do not use `Wait()`!

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. Your code is doing things wrongly which is why you are getting this exception. Solve the problem by fixing your code, not trying to force DbContext to behave in a way that you think will fix the problem (it won't).

Comment: why is startup even coming into the picture here?  your unit test should be creating the context and passing that to component that needs the context.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue (mostly). There was another reason the code wasn't working, it had to do with the way I seeded my database using the db context. This issue does not keep my tests from running and passing, so I will leave it for now and possibly come back to it later.

Answer (score -1):

Warning : Generally `DbConnection` implementations [aren't thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828953/sharing-a-db-connection-between-threads-in-a-c-sharp-application). I don't recommend to do this.

---

You can specify the unique `SqliteConnexion` in `UseSqlite` like :

```cs
var sqliteConnexion = new SqliteConnection(sqliteConnectionString);
services.AddDbContext<DbContext, InventoryDbContext>(
    (servicesProvider, options) =>
        options.UseSqlite(sqliteConnexion , o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)
);
```

You can also inject the connection as a service like :

```cs
services.AddSingleton<SqliteConnection>(() => new SqliteConnection(sqliteConnectionString));
services.AddDbContext<DbContext, InventoryDbContext>(
    (servicesProvider, options) =>
        options.UseSqlite(servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<SqliteConnection>(), o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)
);
```

Comment: I tried adding the connection like you suggest, it causes an exception: `The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ST\source\repos\src\WebApp\testDb.db' because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: Sound `SqliteConneciton` isn't thread safe. I added a warning about this.

Comment: The solution is my answer do that you want... but it's add other problems. The original error is a mismatch between the transaction and the connection. Maybe you can try to fix it.